# java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package fxml in both module mygame and module gamebase

Tags: java, javafx, module, fxml

I am developing a little game with java 15 and javafx 15.
I decided to develop my game in two java modules to separate the code from the main menu, options and anything that can be reused in other games. My second module comes to complete the first with the interfaces and the mechanics of the game.
Thus, I can reuse my first module later to make other games.

I want my two modules to use javafx.fxml
The problem is, I get an error when I add the fxml in the second module.

I get the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package fxml in both module zuma and module gamebase
```

I believe this error means that I cannot import javafx.fxml into both modules at the same time.

How could I go about using fxml with my two modules?

My module-info :

```
module gamebase {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens polurax.gamebase.controller to javafx.fxml;
    exports polurax.gamebase.controller;
    exports polurax.gamebase.open;
}
```

```
module zuma {
    requires gamebase;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens polurax.zuma.controller to javafx.fxml;
    exports polurax.zuma.controller;
}
```

Comment: There error is telling you there's a package named `fxml` in both **your** modules. The module system does not allow so-called "split packages". You'll have to rename one of the packages to something else.

Comment: Thank you, the problem came from the fact that I had an fxml directory in the resource directory of my two modules